# boost::algorithm::compare & const char

Tags: c++, boost, compare

Using `#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>` to compare `std::string` with `std::vector<std::string>`

```
std::string commandLine

std::string::size_type position

std::string delimiters[] = {" ", ",", "(", ")", ";", "=", ".", "*", "-"};
std::vector<std::string> lexeme(std::begin(delimiters), std::end(delimiters));
```

The comparison

```
while (!boost::algorithm::contains(lexeme, std::to_string(commandLine.at(position)))){
    position--;
}
```

Generates the following error

```
Error   1   error C2679: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const char' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

`const char`?  Am I not defining strings?

Comment: Could you construct a minimal testcase?

Comment: Under "The Comparison" above is the actual code (or testcase) that generated the error using `boost::algorithm::compare`

Comment: I meant a complete source with headers and declarations that people can copy paste and try for themselves. Real code, like 10 lines long or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`boost::algorithm::contains`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/algorithm/contains.html) tests whether one *sequence* is contained in another, not whether one *item* is contained in a sequence. You're passing a sequence of strings, and a sequence of characters (aka a string); hence the error when it tries to compare a string with a character.

Instead, if you want to find a string in a sequence of strings, use `std::find`:

```
while (std::find(lexeme.begin(), lexeme.end(), 
                 std::to_string(commandLine.at(position))) == lexeme.end())
{
    --position;
}
```

Comment: Missing an extra `)` after `commandLine.at(position)) == ...` and I would be comparing, in a bool fashion, `std::find != lexeme.end()`?

Comment: @Mushy: Yes, there was a missing `)`. Your code is trying to do `while (not found)`, which is `while (find() == end())`, since `find` returns the iterator it finds, or `end()` if it finds nothing.